# Can't bind to DIRECTIVE since it isn't a known property of element Angular AOT

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-aot

I have been trying to no avail to solve my issue.

.html:

```
<li [myHighlight]="color" defaultColor="violet" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['user']">Users <span class="sr-only" >(current)</span></a></li>
```

directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @Input() defaultColor: string;

    @Input('myHighlight') highlightColor: string;

@HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.highlight(this.highlightColor || this.defaultColor || 'red');
}

@HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.highlight(null);
}
    private highlight(color: string) {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

app.module:

```
import { PermissionsDirective, HighlightDirective } from "./shared/directives/permisions.directive";

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
          ..
        ],
        declarations: [
            ..
            HighlightDirective,
            ..
        ],
        bootstrap: [
            ApplicationComponent,
        ],
        providers: [
            ..
        ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Error that i am getting:

```
Can't bind to 'myHighlight' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.
```

I am using AOT compiler with these settings:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
          .. all the good stuff ..
    ],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "genDir": "aot",
        "skipMetadataEmit": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "buildOnSave": true
}
```

My guess is that because of AOT compiler i'm supposed to define the directive differently than they do in guides. 
[This](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#write-directive) is the guide i used. I also watched a pluralsight course on this but everything seems to run fine for others. Can someone point me in the right direction? I wouldn't be here if i hadn't been looking for hours...

EDIT: Why does it think that 'myHighlight' is a property of "li" while 'routerLinkActive' is (i hope) a property of the router directive?

Comment: I just noticed that the generated ngFactory from app.module doesn't contain imports for my directives. I'm going to investigate a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that i 'declared' the directive in the main application.module instead of the one that was using it. I still don't get it why each module has to declare its own directives that it will be using instead of declaring them once in the main module.

Comment: add the directive not just to declarations, but also to exports in main module